# Three way ANOVA in R and emmeans : compute means by group

Tags: r, linear-regression, emmeans

I made the following linear model in R

```
mod <- lm(response ~ (Parent+Children)*Day , data= data)
```

Parent is a variable with 2 levels, Children with 4 levels
(I've already check there is no interaction in Parent & Children)

Is there a way to compute pairs means just focusing on Parent at the first place and children at the second place in one function

Basically, I want to make :

```
emmeans(mod, ~ Parent | Day*Children)
emmeans(mod, ~ Children | Day*Parent)
```

at once, just in one call of emmeans

I've tried :

```
emmeans(mod, Parent+Children|Day)
```

but it makes all possible comparisons (which I don't want)

Thank you in advance

Valentin

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. Could you provide us with some example data, and the outupt that you want to get?

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg